# How do I put all the items in a list through a looping function?

Tags: python, list, function, loops

This program inputs all of the items into the letter[] list and is supposed to loop them them in to go through the getLetter function but it isn't working. The program below only outputs the last item of the list through the getLetter function.

```
import time, sys

def getLetter(letter):
    while True:
        if letter =='A'or letter=='a':
            print('  *  ')
            return
            break
        if letter =='B'or letter=='b':
            print('  **  ')
            return
            break


print('Enter each character individually')
letterInput=[]

while True:
    print('Enter letter number ' + str(len(letterInput)+1),end='')
    print('. Enter nothing to stop.')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    letter = input()
    if letter == '':
        break
    letterInput=letterInput+[letter]
    
print('These are the letters you have inputted:')
for letter in letterInput:
    print(' '+letter)
    

while True:
    for i in range(len(letter)):
        output=getLetter(letter[i])
```

Comment: just a note: `break` after `return` has no meaning

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Comment: The last `for` loop isn't looping through the `letterInput`, it is only looping through the last `letter`. A better syntax for that for loop would also be `for val in letterInput: output=getLetter(val)`. Also, you don't need the last `While True:`

Comment: your `getLetter` function is going to hang your program `if letter.lower() not in {'a', 'b'}`.  Why are you doing everything in `while True` loops?

Comment: For starters you have an infinite loop running the `getLetter` function, if the letter is not A/a/B/b.  Second, line 34 should reference `letterInput`, not `letter`.

Comment: I think I get that you read user input letter by letter until '' is entered. But I can't work out what if the `getLetter` function support to do -maybe try to explain it. What I see later in the loop is that you think you are assigning a value to variable output but in fact you are assigning None. I reckon you you would benefit from Raymond's awesome video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go&t=2270s, there are many weird looking things to a python programmer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to append an item to a list you should use:

```
letterInput.append(letter)
```

You code has more problems:

I tried to fix it but I not really know what the script should do.
See:

```
import time, sys


def getLetter(letter):
    if letter == 'A' or letter == 'a':
        return '  *  '
    if letter == 'B' or letter == 'b':
        return '  **  '
    return ''


print('Enter each character individually')
letterInput = []

while True:
    print('Enter letter number ' + str(len(letterInput) + 1), end='')
    print('. Enter nothing to stop.')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    letter = input()
    if letter == '':
        break
    letterInput.append(letter)

print('These are the letters you have inputted:')
for letter in letterInput:
    print(' ' + letter)

for letter_value in letterInput:
    output = getLetter(letter_value)
    print(output)
```

Like [@Samwise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799759/samwise) in comments said, you could use this:

```
def getLetter(letter):
    # letter is 'a' or 'A'
    if letter.lower() == 'a':
        return '  *  '
    # letter is 'b' or 'B'
    if letter.lower() == 'b':
        return '  **  '
    # letter is NOT 'a', 'A', 'b' or 'B'
    return ''
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I'm presuming upon some gaps left in the description about how you want the output to work, so this is **just an example of some major simplifications** which can be applied.

Here are some more Pythonic methods which can be used in place of your JavaScript-like syntax:

```
def getLetter(letters):
    for i in letters:
        if i.lower() =='a':
            print('  *  ')
        elif i.lower() == 'b':
            print('  **  ')
 
letters = input('Enter a string of letters: ')

print('These are the letters you have inputted: ', letters)
getLetter(letters)
```

#### Input:

```
abcdef
```

#### Output:

```
These are the letters you have inputted:  abcdef
  *  
  **
```

Comment: thanks for replying! what does i.lower() do in comparison to just i?

Comment: No worries mate, my pleasure.  Please upvote if it’s helped you; and if you have already, thank you.  As for `i.lower()`, this is a string function to convert the value of `i` to lower case; thus only needing to compare `”a”`.  May I recommend a beginning Python course, might be very beneficial.

Comment: Could you recommend a Python course for total beginners like me?

Comment: A quick DuckDuck search will turn up loads, from [full courses](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/python) to more [simple ones](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at cleaning up this script to make it work better and hopefully to make it easier for you to add on to it.  Some specific notes:

1. Don't put everything in `while True` loops for no reason.  It makes sense in the context of your input loop; in the other places it seems like you're doing it for no particular reason, and it's very likely to make your program hang since you don't have a way to ensure that the loop is broken in each case.
2. The standard convention in Python is to name things like `get_letter` instead of `getLetter`.  This is a good habit to establish early!
3. I implemented your `get_letter` function in such a way as to reduce code duplication and to have it raise an exception if it gets unexpected input, rather than hanging forever.
4. Use `for letter in letters` rather than `for i in range(len(letters))`!
5. Use `letters.append(letter)` rather than `letters = letters + [letter]`.
6. Get familiar with `f"strings"` and `str.join()`; these are really useful ways to format strings easily.

```
import time


def get_letter(letter: str) -> str:
    letter_symbols = {
        'a': '*',
        'b': '**',
    }
    return f'  {letter_symbols[letter.lower()]}  '


print('Enter each character individually')
letters = []
while True:
    print(
        f"Enter letter number {(len(letters)+1)}. "
        "Enter nothing to stop."
    )
    time.sleep(0.5)
    letter = input()
    if not letter:
        break
    letters.append(letter)

print('These are the letters you have inputted:')
print(' '.join(letters))


for letter in letters:
    print(get_letter(letter))
```

Comment: wowza thats really compact! thanks for all the help!

I have some questions:
why use letter.lower instead of just letter?

Comment: If you use `letter.lower()`, then you don't need to handle `'A'` separately from `'a'` and so on.  In other words, if you want to treat uppercase and lowercase the same, just turn the input into lowercase and then have the rest of your code deal with the lowercase version of the check.